# How to import Python external libraries with Alexa Skill Kit SDK?

Tags: python, import, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a skill using Alexa Skill Kit SDK on Amazon Developer Console. My code has `import numpy`, which generates a runtime error.

All solutions that I have googled are about uploading numpy source code onto AWS, which I do not find it relevant to the Alexa Skill Kit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are building an Alexa-hosted skill in python.

As the [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/it/docs/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#dependencies) says:

> You can use Python to install dependencies. You add dependencies in
>   the requirements.txt file. An example of the code is shown below:
>
> ```
> boto3==1.9.216
> ```

Comment: Does this version number needs to be exact?  How to find correct version number for any dependency eg.  io ?

Comment: You can put the dependency without the version, but it will install the latest. You can search for dependencies for example in pypi, you can find the version number. Putting the number allows you to have full control on dependencies version, otherwise you will have the latest.