# How to import feedparser as external package in Alexa-host custom skill

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to  `import` and use `feedparser` in **Alexa hosted** python skill.

It works fine before I write  `import feedparser` but as soon I add import feedparser it says:

> *There was a problem with the requested skill's response*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import Python external libraries with Alexa Skill Kit SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779561/how-to-import-python-external-libraries-with-alexa-skill-kit-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

As `feedparser` is an external package, you'll need to install it before you can import it. Normally, you'd do this by running e.g. `pip install feedparser` in the terminal, but you can't do that in the Developer Console. Instead, add the packages that you want use in the `requirements.txt` file, found in the directory tree on the left.

So for `feedparser` add a row which reads:

`feedparser>=5.2.1`

(5.2.1 is the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/) of feedparser currently available.)

This is [briefly covered in the Alexa Skills Kit docs](https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#dependencies) as well.